# Stripe Connect - I see private transactions from connected account in my main Stripe account

Tags: php, stripe-payments, privacy

I have a marketplace website with a Stripe account for processing payments. I have a number of suppliers and I have set them up using Stripe connect. After payment, the appropriate amounts are sent to the suppliers connected stripe accounts and I take a fee, sent to my main Stripe account.

The problem I have is that in my dashboard in Stripe.com when looking at my suppliers connected accounts I can see ALL of their transactions, not just the ones related to sales on my website. If they make a payment or receive money outside of my website I can see that in my Stripe.com dashboard.

The Connection (PHP)

```
$response = \Stripe\OAuth::token( [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'code'       => $code,
        ] );
```

We are ready to go live with this site and obviously cant do so with this issue.

I am unable to find the related documentation on the stripe website. Can anyone let me know how to restrict my view to only see transactions from connected accounts that happen on my website?

Comment: I'm not sure this is your problem to solve. This looks like a serious issue with the Stripe system. I'd report a possible bug to them.

Comment: Are you using  Standard Connect Accounts and Direct charges ? 
If so, keep in mind that they can process charges on their own:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts#standard-accounts:~:text=A%20Standard%20Stripe%20account%20is%20a%20conventional%20Stripe%20account%20where%20the%20account%20holder%20(that%20is%2C%20your%20platform%E2%80%99s%20user)%20has%20a%20relationship%20with%20Stripe%2C%20is%20able%20to%20log%20in%20to%20the%20Dashboard%2C%20and%20can%20process%20charges%20on%20their%20own.

Comment: @os4m37 Yes I use a standard connect account. I use payment intents to setup the payment on the main account then do a transfer to connected accounts.

Comment: You should be using Destination Charge or Separate Charges and Transfers in this case, using Custom or Express Connect Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected for Standard Accounts - you will be able to see all of their transaction data, irrespective of what application it's coming from.

I would suggest using Express accounts (Custom is also a solution, though it's a large change integration-wise). These accounts can only have one platform, so any transaction on their account would originate from you.
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-express-accounts

Another thing you could do is delve into Stripe's new 'Stripe App' system, which might provide the best granular permissions for your accounts:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-apps/create-app

Comment: It's not recommended to use Oauth, you should be using AccountLinks instead:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts

Comment: That's true ^. However they appear to be using Oauth for their Standard accounts and switching to Express Oauth would be the fastest way to get into production whilst also fixing their issue. Still a good point to make.